# tkinter askopenfilename doubleclick passes event to parent

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tkinter

I have this simple example of the behavior:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk

INITIALDIR = 'C:\\'

class MainWindow(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(root, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pack()
        btnoptions = {'expand':True, 'fill': 'both'}
        btn = ttk.Button(self, text='Select', command=self.ask_openfile)
        btn.pack(**btnoptions)

    def ask_openfile(self):
        self.file_opt = options = {}
        options['initialdir'] = INITIALDIR
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(**self.file_opt)
        return filename

if __name__=='__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('600x300')
    MainWindow(root).pack(expand=True, fill='both', side='top')
    root.mainloop()
```

Basically there is one big button, which opens a open file dialog. If I select a file and press open, it works fine. However, if I double click to select a file, it selects the file, closes the dialog, and immediately opens a new open file dialog. My guess, that the second click somehow is passed to the underlying window and it clicks on the button again (button has to be under the file which is about to be selected). Is there a way to avoid this behavior? Looks like it is Windows problem, tried on windows 7 and 10 with python 3.5. On debian linux everything is fine, however, I need this to work on Windows.

Comment: disable the button in ask_openfle() if you are indeed clicking it a second time, i.e. state=DISABLED http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm or pack_forget() to remove it.

Comment: what version of python is this on? This is a bug that is on windows platforms, but was fixed years ago IIRC.

Comment: With 3.5.1 on Win10, running from IDLE editor, I do not get the dialog reappearing.  I added `print(filename)` to confirm that dialog got name.  I tried twice to make sure I was double-clicking fast enough.

Comment: This is python 3.5.1 on windows 10 (the same on win7 with the same python version (both 64bit and 32bit)) running from the script, not from idle.

Comment: Tried running from idle, got exactly the same. And I don't need to doubleclick "very" fast, normal doubleclick is enough to get this behavior.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you find a solution to this? I'm having the exact same issue, it only happens on very first file in each folder (sporadically too!)

Comment: I've added a property has_file, which is set once file is selected. In the function which opens file dialog, I check if the file is selected, then do nothing, else open a dialog. Need to remember to unset that property once you are done with the file.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a known issue with tk:
https://core.tcl.tk/tk/tktview?name=faf37bd379

That ticket says that the issue is fixed in tk 8.6.8.

I was having this issue with tk 8.6 and updating isn't a great option so I tried to find some other workarounds. I tried disabling the buttons and then enabling them but the rouge click just occurred after the button was enabled. I also tried adding a delay before enabling the buttons again but that didn't work either.

The two workarounds that I found that actually worked are:
1) Change the buttons to require a double-click. This can be done with bind . I don't personally like having to double-click the button but maybe other people are less picky.
2) Change the file selection to a combobox with a list of the files in a selected directory. The directory can be selected using askdirectory in place of askopenfilename. askdirectory requires the user to click the "Select Folder" button so it does not have the same issue with double-clicks.